# Hover state on css pseudo class

Tags: html, css, class, selector

I have a sub menu with 4 headers. The code below styles the first element of each column of the submenu.

What I need to do now is apply a hover state for these, making the background of each grey on hover. Am now sure where :hover should go in the code I have provided below.

So for example where I have the background set to background-color:#3498db on hover I want this to become grey.

Thanks.

```
#ms-topmenu .row > div:nth-child(2) a:nth-child(1){
    background-color:#3498db;
    padding:5px;
    color:white;
}

#ms-topmenu .row > div:nth-child(3) a:nth-child(1){
    background-color:#2ecc71;
    padding:5px;
    color:white;
}

#ms-topmenu  .row > div:nth-child(4) a:nth-child(1){
    background-color:#9b59b6;
    padding:5px;
    color:white;
}

#ms-topmenu .row > div:nth-child(5) a:nth-child(1){
    background-color:#e67e22;
    padding:5px;
    color:white;
}
```

Comment: Need to see your HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do so as follows:

```
#ms-topmenu .row > div:nth-child(2) a:nth-child(1):hover {
    background: grey;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may can try this:

```css
#ms-topmenu .row > div:nth-child(2) a:nth-child(1){
    background-color:#3498db;
    padding:5px;
    color:white;
}

#ms-topmenu .row > div:nth-child(3) a:nth-child(1){
    background-color:#2ecc71;
    padding:5px;
    color:white;
}

#ms-topmenu  .row > div:nth-child(4) a:nth-child(1){
    background-color:#9b59b6;
    padding:5px;
    color:white;
}

#ms-topmenu .row > div:nth-child(5) a:nth-child(1){
    background-color:#e67e22;
    padding:5px;
    color:white;
}

#ms-topmenu .row > div a:hover {
    background-color : #AAA !important;
}

/* This code is only for make the example looks better */
#ms-topmenu .row > div {
  display : inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="ms-topmenu">
    <div class="row">
        <div>
          <a href="#">Say Hello</a>
        </div>
        <div>
          <a href="#">Say Hello</a>
        </div>
        <div>
          <a href="#">Say Hello</a>
        </div>
        <div>
          <a href="#">Say Hello</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```